# Understanding Stripe's API authentication

Tags: api, authentication, stripe-payments, basic-authentication

Stripe's API uses HTTP Basic Authentication over HTTPS for authentication. Per the [**instructions**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#authentication), this requires including a secret API key in the request.

However, the Stripe dashboard provides us with two keys, one public and one secret. What is the public key used for?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pk_*` keys are used in javascript client, since everyone can view this key by looking at html source code.

If someone obtains this `public key` there're only few operations that they can do e.g. collecting credit card info, request for tokens etc.

In contrast, your `secret key` are used for all crucial operations e.g. charge a credit card, create new customer etc.

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_*');
```

see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js